# How to make a text box in android without changing the theme?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, mobile

I tried o follow another post and change the theme of my app to Theme.light but that broke my project so I reverted to my original theme that the blank activity starts with. I am building an app with a basic calculator feature and I want to style the EditTexts into text boxes but I don't want to change the theme of my app. Any ideas?? Thank you for any help you can provide!!

Comment: create your own custom style. check [this](http://stacktips.com/tutorials/android/android-styles-and-themes-tutorial)

Comment: Thank you for this, while I chose the other answer this is going to be a huge help as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to make some text box you could use the following attribute for EditText:

```
android:background="@android:drawable/editbox_background_normal"
```

So it would look like below. Hope that helps.

[image]